# Does current flow inside a battery?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, batteries, electrochemistry

When connected in a circuit, does current flow inside a battery. If yes, in which direction?

Comment: We call them "circuits" because the current flows in (unbroken) circles.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See [Electrochemical cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrochemical_cell)

Comment: Without continuous current, the formed charge disbalance would very quickly form potential countergradients, ceasing any external current. As hydraulic analogy, the cell chemistry is like a water pump, forcing continuous water current through closed tube circuit, or keeping different water levels  if the tube circuit is open.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. When a battery is operating normally then current flows inside the battery from the negative terminal to the positive terminal.

Comment: If it flows from the negative terminal to the positive terminal, then isn't the battery supposed to last forever as the charge difference between the positive and negative terminals don't change?

Comment: @Sayn, there are chemical reactions going on between the electrodes and the dielectric to support this current. When the reagents for these reactions are exhausted, then the reaction can't continue, the current stops, and we say the battery is "dead".